# What is the industry standard solution for creating a deployment using CI (Jenkins) using kubectl set image command in kubernetes

Tags: jenkins, kubernetes, continuous-deployment

Currently I am working with implementation demo of CI/CD pipeline using Jenkins and kubernetes. I am created one Jenkins pipeline job and added every step in my Jenkinsfile. For kubernetes , I created deployment and service YAML files for Kubernetes resources.

**Image Version Management In deployment**

For each commit in my SVN repository , I am creating docker images by adding the tag as build number through Jenkins environment variable.

```
image:1
image:2
.
.
image:n
```

**Confusion**

If I am using `kubectl set image` command for updating my deployment in my Jenkinsfile deployment stage , then It will work for first commit ?

I felt this confusion , because command says that it is for updating the deployment if there is change in image defined in YAML file. So If I am changing image for each commit according to build number( image-name:buildnumber) , then if there is no deployment exits , it will work for first time?

Comment: Hi Jacob, can you elaborate on your confusion.

Comment: @damitj07 - I modified the confusion how I felt in question. Guide me If I went in wrong way. My confusion is that for using `kubectl set image` for first deployment in my pipeline.Can you look on question please?

Comment: For the first time, you will have to manually create the deployment. This is more of flow issue I think. So let the first build fail as there will be no deployment. Then create a deployment and set it to first image version . It will work from second time  onwards

Comment: Or you can add a simple conditional check-in your Jenkins, for the first time if deployment does not exists create it and set it to the first image. And from the second commit onwards update.

Comment: @damitj07- Thank you for your response. My application going to use complete automation for deployment by using SVN, jenkins and Kubernetes. So If I am manually doing first deployment , then is that a standard way of CI/CD ? like the same every DevOps developers do? , I am new to DevOps , I am finding standard way . By using helm chart it is possible create/update. I already completed Its R&D. Now need to do without helm chart , only using kubernetes deployment and service resources.

Comment: @damitj07 - yes by checking with build number , I can create if it is first deployment or I can update using `kubectl rollout restart` is that what it is? . Please correct me If I went in wrong way.

Comment: yes , SO think of it as each repo' has its own deployment.yml  inside it. So when for first time code is checked-in you can use that yml to check if deployment already excists ? if it does not just create the development with `kubectl apply`  or in case of second commit `kubectl set image ` will work

Comment: @damitj07 -  Yes I have its own deployment.yaml and service.yaml inside it. And I understood the commands both apply and set image. But why I need to use yml to check if deployment already exists? I did not understood that sentense . Can you clarify for me please?

Comment: You just need the name or some way to recognize if it is first commit or not. And you can use any method to do it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So I can think of multiple ways, one a bit hacky and other that I like. You can decide based on waht is best suited for you.

**Solution 1** - You can add a simple conditional check-in your Jenkins, for the first time if deployment does not exists create it and set it to the first image. And from the second commit onwards update.

OR

**Solution 2** - Think of it as each repository or service should have its own `deployment.yml` within it. So when for first time code is checked-in you can use that yml to check if deployment already exists ? if it does not just create the development with `kubectl apply myapp.yml` and for the second commit `kubectl set image` will work.

Comment: Yes. I understood the ways.Let me  try.